# PHP - sending GET request with cURL

Tags: php, curl, get

I am following documentation in the RackSpace API to create a temp URL to a file in our cloud files.  It appears I need to send a GET request to a specific URL, but there are these other 2 parameters I don't understand how they get passed.  I am using cURL for the GET request.

Here is the sample code:

```
<?php
if ($argc != 5) {
    echo "Syntax: <method> <url> <seconds> <key>";
    echo "Example: GET https://storage101.dfw1.clouddrive.com/v1/" .
         "MossoCloudFS_12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0/" .
         "container/my_cat.jpg 60 my_shared_secret_key";
} else {
  $method = $argv[1];
  $url = $argv[2];
  $seconds = $argv[3];
  $key = $argv[4];
  $method = strtoupper($method);
  list($base_url, $object_path) =  split("/v1/", $url);
  $object_path = "/v1/$object_path";
  $seconds = (int)$seconds;
  $expires = (int)(time() + $seconds);
  $hmac_body = "$method\n$expires\n$object_path";
  $sig = hash_hmac("sha256", $hmac_body, $key);
  echo "$base_url$object_path?" .
       "temp_url_sig=$sig&temp_url_expires=$expires";
}
?>
```

And it says this line above that code which may help: "In the following examples, a TempURL that will be available for 60 seconds is generated for the my_cat.jpg object. The key in the examples is the value of X-Account-Meta-Temp-Url-Key."

I've already set the "X-Account-Meta-Temp-Url-Key" header with a POST command previous to this.

Basically, I am confused about how to pass the '60' and the 'my_shared_secret_key' in with the URL.

Here is the full documentation: https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/v1/use-cases/public-access-to-your-cloud-files-account/#tempurl

Comment: if the server needs a GET request, you just can pass parameters in the URL, like the examples says

Comment: OK, so with the included spaces like so: `https://urlpath/my_cat.jpg 60 dr423fI8seD`

Comment: Looking the example it is the right way.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work.  Getting `400 Bad request
Your browser sent an invalid request.`

Comment: Do not you have the documentation of the API?

Comment: I added it now.